# Microsoft Graph API using I'm not able to event create or update in php , Is it possible only for invited users or any other way?

Tags: php

I want to access Microsoft Graph from a console application in order to copy messages from an Outlook calendar event create. I had to use the Microsoft Graph's Client Credentials Flow.

These are the steps I have take:

1 . Register an App in the Azure portal and create a Client Secret for it.

2 . Add all the permissions I need and grant them access

3 . Request for auth consent : This is done using the following URL:

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=AppId&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://localhost&response_mode=query&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendars.ReadWrite`

4 . Get user access token for following method

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJOwb.png)

5 . I try to access calendar details or event create , get this error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdPvL.png)

Comment: [Please do not post images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/6089612)